# Accessories combinations

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, combinations, prestashop-1.6

I would like to display "combinations" of the accessories on `product.tpl`.
Which could function to use please?

```
group_$id_attribute_group
```

This syntax seems not work with *$accessory*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following functions in Product class to fetch all the product combinations:

```
getAttributeCombinations()
```

Following function will help you in fetching attribute images:

```
getCombinationImages()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For now it's the combination of the main product and not of the accessories displayed: http://imageshack.com/a/img923/7697/ARz7bG.jpg